# Como retirar barra de url e botões de um webview browser

Tags: android, webview, kotlin

Olá, sou novato em kotlin e estou utilizando um [Projeto](https://github.com/QuaestioOrg/android-kotlin-webview) em webview para espelhar um site no App. 
Porém, a unica pagina que vem perfeita é a home, os links externos o App utiliza de um WebView Browser. 
Eu gostaria de esconder a barra de url desse Browser ou se possível, puxar os links externos igual é puxado a home.

MainActivity.kt

```
package org.quaestio.kotlinconvertedwebview

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_webview.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)

    val mWebView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)

    val webSettings = mWebView.settings
    webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    mWebView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.website_url))
    mWebView.webViewClient = HelloWebViewClient()
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(false)

}


private inner class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
        if (Uri.parse(url).host == getString(R.string.website_domain)) {
            return false
        }
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
        startActivity(intent)
        return true
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
    }

}

override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack()
        return true
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true"
            tools:targetApi="m">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="smb-django.herokuapp.com/"
                android:scheme="https://smb-django.herokuapp.com/" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
        android:value="true" />
</application>
```

Agradeço imensamente por quem puder me ajudar de alguma forma.

Comment: Para ocultar a barra você pode usar o metodo `shouldOverrideURLLoading()` do webView. O botão eu já não sei.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Oque eu precisava na verdade era acessar links externos dentro do proprio aplicativo sem chamar um navegador para abri-lo. resolvi este problema com o esse [Projeto](https://github.com/matheus-ereira/Projeto-Kotlin). Obrigado a todos pela ajuda :)

Answer (score -2):

Alguns fatores podem causar esse comportamento, um deles é a versão da API que está executando sua WebView, verifique a versão da API. 
Mas algumas configurações podem ajudar a resolver esse comportamento, como:

```
    mWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    mWebView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled (true)
    mWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    mWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    mWebView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
    mWebView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
```